# Redirecting example.com to www.example.com in Go Daddy

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, google-app-engine

If I go to `http://www.example.com/`, it's perfectly fine. If I go to `http://example.com/`, then it redirects me to Go Daddy's site.

I'm using Google App Engine to host my site, as it's free and pretty cool, and I've not bought the hosting option from Go Daddy.

How exactly do I change it to have both the **example.com** and **www.example.com** versions go where they're supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

See [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain) for details on setting up the Google side of things (essentially, add a new URL and make the necessary DNS changes). You will need a CNAME (type of DNS record) for the www subdomain, but I believe GoDaddy enables those by default.

If you need to change your DNS settings on GoDaddy, you can access the DNS Manager from:

1. Login to GoDaddy
2. Hover over Domains, and click Domain Management
3. Click the domain you are want to modify
4. Scroll down to 'DNS Manager', click Launch

Details about the different DNS records and using them with GoDaddy can be found in [GoDaddy's Help](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#cnames)

Answer (score 0):

In the records if you set * to the ip address then it will forward all subdomains to that IP.

So you should see something like

*--> x.x.x.x

@--> x.x.x.x

www -->  @

You will also want to make sure that you set up your apache (if using virtual hosts to accept the blank subdomain)